# Karate - how to wait for assertion (negative assertion)

Tags: automated-tests, karate

Using Karate I need to use assertion (negative assertion) but I need some repetitive check.

Example: when I delete application, it takes some time when it is removed from User Interface. I need to check If the app name is still there or not (every 3 seconds). If it is not present (the appName do not exist on page) then next test steps follow.

For assertion I use:

```
assert !locate('{//*[normalize-space(text()) = \'' + appName + '\']}').exists
```

Could you please help me with idea how to do periodically (every 3 sec) check the appName existence? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`waitUntil()`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#waituntil)

```
* def fun = function(){ return !locate('#foo').exists ? true : null }
* waitUntil(fun)
```

EDIT: please also note this API revision we will be doing for 0.9.6 final: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1148